# Xcode (clang) error when compiling Mac application

Tags: xcode, macos, clang

I'm trying to compile a Mac application but Xcode gives me this error:

```
ProcessPCH /Users/pedrofranceschi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-ezqihosacfpbfbdsrtmsgtbnvjmk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/myproj-Prefix-epkmwajobvayuietjwkbptfdivuu/myproj-Prefix.pch.pth myproj/myproj-Prefix.pch normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/pedrofranceschi/Desktop/TUDO/myproj
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c-header -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -g -Wno-sign-conversion "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -iquote /Users/pedrofranceschi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-ezqihosacfpbfbdsrtmsgtbnvjmk/Build/Intermediates/myproj.build/Debug/myproj.build/myproj-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/pedrofranceschi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-ezqihosacfpbfbdsrtmsgtbnvjmk/Build/Intermediates/myproj.build/Debug/myproj.build/myproj-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/pedrofranceschi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-ezqihosacfpbfbdsrtmsgtbnvjmk/Build/Intermediates/myproj.build/Debug/myproj.build/myproj-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/pedrofranceschi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-ezqihosacfpbfbdsrtmsgtbnvjmk/Build/Intermediates/myproj.build/Debug/myproj.build/myproj-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/pedrofranceschi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-ezqihosacfpbfbdsrtmsgtbnvjmk/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/pedrofranceschi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-ezqihosacfpbfbdsrtmsgtbnvjmk/Build/Intermediates/myproj.build/Debug/myproj.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/pedrofranceschi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-ezqihosacfpbfbdsrtmsgtbnvjmk/Build/Intermediates/myproj.build/Debug/myproj.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/pedrofranceschi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-ezqihosacfpbfbdsrtmsgtbnvjmk/Build/Products/Debug --serialize-diagnostics /Users/pedrofranceschi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-ezqihosacfpbfbdsrtmsgtbnvjmk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/myproj-Prefix-epkmwajobvayuietjwkbptfdivuu/myproj-Prefix.pch.dia -c /Users/pedrofranceschi/Desktop/TUDO/myproj/myproj/myproj-Prefix.pch -o /Users/pedrofranceschi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-ezqihosacfpbfbdsrtmsgtbnvjmk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/myproj-Prefix-epkmwajobvayuietjwkbptfdivuu/myproj-Prefix.pch.pth -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/pedrofranceschi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-ezqihosacfpbfbdsrtmsgtbnvjmk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/myproj-Prefix-epkmwajobvayuietjwkbptfdivuu/myproj-Prefix.pch.d

i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1: /Users/pedrofranceschi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-ezqihosacfpbfbdsrtmsgtbnvjmk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/myproj-Prefix-epkmwajobvayuietjwkbptfdivuu/myproj-Prefix.pch.dia: No such file or directory
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-implicit-atomic-properties"
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-receiver-is-weak"
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wduplicate-method-match"
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-deprecated-implementations"
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-sign-conversion"
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-fobjc-arc"
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-fserialize-diagnostics"
cc1obj: warning: -Wuninitialized is not supported without -O
Command /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Any ideas?

Regards,

Pedro

Comment: You're not running clang - you're running gcc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The errors you're getting are because of project settings. This was
   most likely an older project, built up on on older version of OS X / SDK
   than what you're currently running. Take the errors one by one and search
   what's causing each of them.  For example,

   ```
   cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-implicit-atomic-properties"
   ```

   is related to Implicit Atomic Objective-C Properties LLVM compiler
   warning enabled in your project settings. Try removing this setting
   and check if you still get the error, and so on.
2. Also check if your Command Line Tools are installed properly, since
   this seems to be a command line tools issue. They are separate download. Go To XCode / Preferences / Downloads / Components and you should you have an item in the list with the name Command Line tools, which should have the status "Installed". If it doesn't, download and install it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! My command line tools were not working correctly. After a reinstall, everything is working. :)